# Does every operating system come with its own assembler?

Tags: operating-system

I am new in operating system. ****Does every operating system come with its own assembler? C program is internally converted to assembly program . Does compiler come with its own assembler or it uses default assembler provided by operating system(if operating system has its own assembler).****

Comment: A compiler should generate byte code or assembler for the target platform.  "It's own" sounds like byte code, but ultimately the virtual machine that executes the byte code would have to use assembler for the target operating system.

Answer (score 0):

> Does every operating system come with its own assembler? C program is internally converted to assembly program .

No.

Windoze is one such example.

> Does compiler come with its own assembler or it uses default assembler provided by operating system(if operating system has its own assembler)

Most compilers I am aware of generate object code directly and do not use an assembler. If the compiler generates assembly, either the compiler source needs to supply an assembler or generate code that is compatible with the system assembler.

Comment: Then what is the use of instruction set architecture without assembler

Comment: isa is set of instructions that the processor understand .to convert a source code to machine code we need the instructions that the cpu understand how can a machine code be created without that knowledge (ISA)